# Can I run computer network wiring next to the furnace exhaust?

Tags: data-wiring

I am in Ontario and I want to run computer networking wire from the basement to the second floor.  The most direct route is inside the box that carries the furnace exhaust to the chimney on the roof.  The wire would be outside the metal furnace exhaust but inside the wooden box that contains the metal pipe.

Comment: Are you asking if it's OK to run the cable next to the exhaust? Or something else?

Comment: Yikes!!!!!  that really needs to be answered by your building inspector.  Canadian Codes are very strict. The plenum cable would have to have the correct stats, if allowed at all.  I really have no idea of a correct answer.  We should ask Mike Holmes, my mentor and great Canadian builder.

Comment: hot flues and toxic electrical insulation are likely not compatible bed mates. Have you considered WiFi?

Comment: No knowledge about the code, but I would look at running a plenum cable up the cold air return.  The exhaust might get hot, particularly down at the bottom near the furnace.

Comment: Have you considered going wireless?

Answer (score 1):

Any chance of running it outside the wooden box? In my old house, there was a small gap down they one side that I was able to push a metal fish tape down all the way to the basement.

Comment: Your comment might be able to add insight to my question about running PVC conduit along side a cold air return gap I've discovered in some photos taken of my house pre-drywall.  Could you add anything to this? http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/24823/should-i-be-able-to-run-some-1-5-pvc-chase-conduits-from-attic-to-basement-next

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the construction of your house. Mine is mostly double brick, so I could just drop cables between the two skins. For the new parts of my house, I tied the ethernet cables onto other cables and pulled then up through the wall cavities. This sounds a lot safer than what you are looking at.

Ethernet is rated at [100m](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_6_cable#Maximum_length) length so the most direct route may not be necessary.